# return all possible combos of DNA

Tags: python, combinations

My code below gives me all possible combinations of DNA. Is there a more efficient, cleaner way to do this? Also, for any bioinformatics or biotech programmers, which modules should I become most familiar with?

```
DNA = 'a', 't', 'g', 'c'


lis = []
def all_combos():
    for a in A:
        for t in A:
            for g in A:
                for c in A:  
                    lis.append([a, t, g, c])
    return lis

print(all_combos())
```

Comment: There is a recursive way. This is probably a terrible question for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to generate the list of all combinations. This will generate `tuple`s instead of `list`s, but I guess that's fine?

```
from itertools import product

lis = list(product('atgc',repeat=4))
```

Here `4` means you want to construct 4-tuples.

The algorithm is of course not faster - complexity-wise - than using the `for` loops, since it is inherently *O(m<sup>n</sup>)* with *m* the number of elements (`len('atgc')`) and `n=4` (the number of elements per tuple). Both algorithms are in terms of big-oh **equally fast** (although there can be differences).

This yields:

```
>>> list(product('atgc',repeat=4))
[('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 't'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'g'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 't', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 't', 't'), ('a', 'a', 't', 'g'), ('a', 'a', 't', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'g', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'g', 't'), ('a', 'a', 'g', 'g'), ('a', 'a', 'g', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 't'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'g'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 't', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 't', 'a', 't'), ('a', 't', 'a', 'g'), ('a', 't', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 't', 't', 'a'), ('a', 't', 't', 't'), ('a', 't', 't', 'g'), ('a', 't', 't', 'c'), ('a', 't', 'g', 'a'), ('a', 't', 'g', 't'), ('a', 't', 'g', 'g'), ('a', 't', 'g', 'c'), ('a', 't', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 't', 'c', 't'), ('a', 't', 'c', 'g'), ('a', 't', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'g', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'g', 'a', 't'), ('a', 'g', 'a', 'g'), ('a', 'g', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'g', 't', 'a'), ('a', 'g', 't', 't'), ('a', 'g', 't', 'g'), ('a', 'g', 't', 'c'), ('a', 'g', 'g', 'a'), ('a', 'g', 'g', 't'), ('a', 'g', 'g', 'g'), ('a', 'g', 'g', 'c'), ('a', 'g', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'g', 'c', 't'), ('a', 'g', 'c', 'g'), ('a', 'g', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 't'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'g'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 't', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 't', 't'), ('a', 'c', 't', 'g'), ('a', 'c', 't', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'g', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'g', 't'), ('a', 'c', 'g', 'g'), ('a', 'c', 'g', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 't'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'g'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('t', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('t', 'a', 'a', 't'), ('t', 'a', 'a', 'g'), ('t', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('t', 'a', 't', 'a'), ('t', 'a', 't', 't'), ('t', 'a', 't', 'g'), ('t', 'a', 't', 'c'), ('t', 'a', 'g', 'a'), ('t', 'a', 'g', 't'), ('t', 'a', 'g', 'g'), ('t', 'a', 'g', 'c'), ('t', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('t', 'a', 'c', 't'), ('t', 'a', 'c', 'g'), ('t', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('t', 't', 'a', 'a'), ('t', 't', 'a', 't'), ('t', 't', 'a', 'g'), ('t', 't', 'a', 'c'), ('t', 't', 't', 'a'), ('t', 't', 't', 't'), ('t', 't', 't', 'g'), ('t', 't', 't', 'c'), ('t', 't', 'g', 'a'), ('t', 't', 'g', 't'), ('t', 't', 'g', 'g'), ('t', 't', 'g', 'c'), ('t', 't', 'c', 'a'), ('t', 't', 'c', 't'), ('t', 't', 'c', 'g'), ('t', 't', 'c', 'c'), ('t', 'g', 'a', 'a'), ('t', 'g', 'a', 't'), ('t', 'g', 'a', 'g'), ('t', 'g', 'a', 'c'), ('t', 'g', 't', 'a'), ('t', 'g', 't', 't'), ('t', 'g', 't', 'g'), ('t', 'g', 't', 'c'), ('t', 'g', 'g', 'a'), ('t', 'g', 'g', 't'), ('t', 'g', 'g', 'g'), ('t', 'g', 'g', 'c'), ('t', 'g', 'c', 'a'), ('t', 'g', 'c', 't'), ('t', 'g', 'c', 'g'), ('t', 'g', 'c', 'c'), ('t', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('t', 'c', 'a', 't'), ('t', 'c', 'a', 'g'), ('t', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('t', 'c', 't', 'a'), ('t', 'c', 't', 't'), ('t', 'c', 't', 'g'), ('t', 'c', 't', 'c'), ('t', 'c', 'g', 'a'), ('t', 'c', 'g', 't'), ('t', 'c', 'g', 'g'), ('t', 'c', 'g', 'c'), ('t', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('t', 'c', 'c', 't'), ('t', 'c', 'c', 'g'), ('t', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('g', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('g', 'a', 'a', 't'), ('g', 'a', 'a', 'g'), ('g', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('g', 'a', 't', 'a'), ('g', 'a', 't', 't'), ('g', 'a', 't', 'g'), ('g', 'a', 't', 'c'), ('g', 'a', 'g', 'a'), ('g', 'a', 'g', 't'), ('g', 'a', 'g', 'g'), ('g', 'a', 'g', 'c'), ('g', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('g', 'a', 'c', 't'), ('g', 'a', 'c', 'g'), ('g', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('g', 't', 'a', 'a'), ('g', 't', 'a', 't'), ('g', 't', 'a', 'g'), ('g', 't', 'a', 'c'), ('g', 't', 't', 'a'), ('g', 't', 't', 't'), ('g', 't', 't', 'g'), ('g', 't', 't', 'c'), ('g', 't', 'g', 'a'), ('g', 't', 'g', 't'), ('g', 't', 'g', 'g'), ('g', 't', 'g', 'c'), ('g', 't', 'c', 'a'), ('g', 't', 'c', 't'), ('g', 't', 'c', 'g'), ('g', 't', 'c', 'c'), ('g', 'g', 'a', 'a'), ('g', 'g', 'a', 't'), ('g', 'g', 'a', 'g'), ('g', 'g', 'a', 'c'), ('g', 'g', 't', 'a'), ('g', 'g', 't', 't'), ('g', 'g', 't', 'g'), ('g', 'g', 't', 'c'), ('g', 'g', 'g', 'a'), ('g', 'g', 'g', 't'), ('g', 'g', 'g', 'g'), ('g', 'g', 'g', 'c'), ('g', 'g', 'c', 'a'), ('g', 'g', 'c', 't'), ('g', 'g', 'c', 'g'), ('g', 'g', 'c', 'c'), ('g', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('g', 'c', 'a', 't'), ('g', 'c', 'a', 'g'), ('g', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('g', 'c', 't', 'a'), ('g', 'c', 't', 't'), ('g', 'c', 't', 'g'), ('g', 'c', 't', 'c'), ('g', 'c', 'g', 'a'), ('g', 'c', 'g', 't'), ('g', 'c', 'g', 'g'), ('g', 'c', 'g', 'c'), ('g', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('g', 'c', 'c', 't'), ('g', 'c', 'c', 'g'), ('g', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 't'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'g'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 't', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 't', 't'), ('c', 'a', 't', 'g'), ('c', 'a', 't', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'g', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'g', 't'), ('c', 'a', 'g', 'g'), ('c', 'a', 'g', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 't'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'g'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 't', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 't', 'a', 't'), ('c', 't', 'a', 'g'), ('c', 't', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 't', 't', 'a'), ('c', 't', 't', 't'), ('c', 't', 't', 'g'), ('c', 't', 't', 'c'), ('c', 't', 'g', 'a'), ('c', 't', 'g', 't'), ('c', 't', 'g', 'g'), ('c', 't', 'g', 'c'), ('c', 't', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 't', 'c', 't'), ('c', 't', 'c', 'g'), ('c', 't', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'g', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'g', 'a', 't'), ('c', 'g', 'a', 'g'), ('c', 'g', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'g', 't', 'a'), ('c', 'g', 't', 't'), ('c', 'g', 't', 'g'), ('c', 'g', 't', 'c'), ('c', 'g', 'g', 'a'), ('c', 'g', 'g', 't'), ('c', 'g', 'g', 'g'), ('c', 'g', 'g', 'c'), ('c', 'g', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'g', 'c', 't'), ('c', 'g', 'c', 'g'), ('c', 'g', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 't'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'g'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 't', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 't', 't'), ('c', 'c', 't', 'g'), ('c', 'c', 't', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'g', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'g', 't'), ('c', 'c', 'g', 'g'), ('c', 'c', 'g', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 't'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'g'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')]
```

Mind that `itertools` usually work *lazily*: they do return an iterator. Since *O(m<sup>n</sup>)* usually blows up fast, it can therefore be useful to use a generator instead of constructing a list: in that case at least you save on memory. Furthermore if *n* is large (like 16 or larger for *m=4*), usually a computer will start having difficulty processing the elements.

Comment: Perhaps update your answer to clarify that the time complexity is not slower than for loops either

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how I could return a specific combo, such as ('a', 'a','a','t') The commas are throwing me off a little

Comment: @bnicholl: I do not really get what you mean with a *specific* combo. `('a','a','a','t')` is part of the list, so it will be emitted (second element).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yup!  Thanks for humoring me.  If you think of it, it is probably worth putting a disclaimer that this is generally a terrible idea, m^n is enormous, and you would usually want an iterator rather than a list if you are doing serious work.

Answer (score 2):

Guess I was beaten while trying this out .. will leave it up just for my statistics.

If what you want is actually all possible permutations (i.e aaaa, aaat, aaag, aaac... ), you can use itertools this way:

```
from itertools import product

print(list(product('atgc', repeat=4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a python function for generating combinations from a list:

itertools.combinations

A person was trying to list all combinations of a list taken two at a time in this post:  [Python - list the combination pair for a function value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985994/python-list-the-combination-pair-for-a-function-value/42986205#42986205)

Comment: combinations is **not** the right tool here, since a permutation does **not** allow repetition. It would only generate `('a','t','g','c')`...

Answer (score 1):

As a student's exercise, your code is readable and does what you want.

I guess the question is, why do you need all these combinations? Practical bioinformatics is, among other things, a mess of file types and formats, and you'll probably encounter some input data using a different alphabet than the one you're working with.

Regarding modules, there are two general-purpose I'll mention. The rest really depends on what specific task you're trying to accomplish. `Biopython` is the more mature and widely supported, but the code base is it's showing it's age. `scikit-bio` is the new kid on the block with beautiful, fully tested code, but with less features and less support for obscure file formats.

Comment: Awesome thanks. And I originally was just messing around with all the different types of ways to find combinations. I'm somewhat new to python, and since I have a biotech/math background(specifically linear algebra), figured I'd start my focus with bioinformatics. Would you say the average bio-programmer is more focused on stats on linear algebra? Those seem to be the two basic maths that are associated with the field

Comment: I'm not sure there exists such a thing as an average bio-programmer :-) I'm hacking on a bioinformatics search tool ATM, so I'm more of a bigdata-bio-devops kinda guy...

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension:

```js
proteins = ['a', 't', 'c', 'g']
all_combos = [x+y for x in proteins for y in proteins]
```